# How to separate the results of a query on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
id  bigint(20) unsigned Incrément automatique    
form_id        mediumint(8)      unsigned [0]    
entry_id       bigint(20)        unsigned    
meta_key       varchar(255)      NULL    
meta_value     longtext          NULL
```

It show data like this :

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">id</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">form_id</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">entry_id</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">meta_key</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">meta_value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">3</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">14</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Address 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">6</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">20</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">7</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">21</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2018-16-05</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">8</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">23</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Product 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">11</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">14</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Address 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">14</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">20</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">15</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">21</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2018-16-05</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">16</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">23</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Product2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">20</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">3</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">14</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Address3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">21</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">3</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">20</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">22</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">3</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">21</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2018-16-05</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">23</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">3</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">23</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Prodcut3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I need is to have something like with a Select request:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">meta_value1</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">meta_value2</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">meta_value3</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">meta_value4</th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Address 1</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2018-16-05</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Product1</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Address 2</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2018-16-05</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Product2</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Address 3</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2018-16-05</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Prodcut3</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry, I agree with your comment in most cases. However, when issuing plain html, it is not bad to build it within SQL. Performances will be quite similar. On the other hand, it makes the query less generic for future use and it is not following the MVC philosophy. Nevertheless, I answered the question the way it was worded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to group your meta_value by entry and concat the meta_value into a string:

```
SELECT entry_id, GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) AS meta_string
FROM your_table
GROUP BY entry_id
```

This will return:

| 1 | Address 1, 1, 2018-16-05, Product 1 |

| 2 | Address 2, 1, 2018-16-05, Product 2 |
etc

Then, you can explode the meta_string and build your table or you can put the html as a separator in your query like:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value ASC SEPARATOR '</td></tr><td>')
```

This will return a meta formated like:

```
Address 1</td><td>1</td><td>2018-16-05</td><td>Product 1
```

As a matter of fact, you will need to add the wrapper for the tr and the first/last td /td either in your query (see next) or in your code.

```
CONCAT('<tr><td>, GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value ASC SEPARATOR '</td></tr><td>', </td></tr>)) AS full_html_row
```

If you need the meta_key for your th, do the same but like this:

```
SELECT entry_id, GROUP_CONCAT(meta_key) AS keys_string
FROM your_table
WHERE entry_id = 1
GROUP BY entry_id
UNION
SELECT entry_id, GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) AS meta_string
FROM your_table
GROUP BY entry_id
```

Another way, to get the results in separated columns, is to use CASE. However, this is not as efficient as pivoting the raw data within PHP or other.

```
SELECT entry_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 14 THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS meta_value1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 20 THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS meta_value2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 21 THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS meta_value3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 23 THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS meta_value4
FROM your_table
GROUP BY entry_id
```

Comment: I cannot think why a string might be more useful than an array.

Comment: Because he said he wants to do the grouping within the Select query and as far as I know, the string is the only way to bring several records on one line. Do you know a better way ?

Comment: It would work with if's also, but that would make a cumbersome query

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for your response. is there a way to have each one on a separate column ?

Comment: @Youshop MySQL has no pivot or transpose function. Therefore, the only way to do what you ask within MySQL would be by using the CASE function. However, this is not very efficient and you would be way better to pivot your data within PHP or whatever language you receive the data within. See my edited answer for the CASE approach. Please upvote the answer if it answers your question.